# how to show website content in android app without using WebView?

Tags: android, parsing, webview

I want to show the web content in my app one way is to do with WebView but I dont want to do this is there some other way ??

web content should open inside the app not in any browser ?

Comment: you do not want webview or browser?

Answer (score 0):

> web content should open inside the app not in any browser ?

=> When you say you don't want to open web content in any browser, I assume you are aware about opening URLs into the Web browser which is itself inside the app. I mean it's not like clicking on link redirects you to native browser like chrome or any other.

BTW, One alternate way of fetching and displaying web data is **Web Services**.